# Trouble assigning pointers from a table in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create a graph from a file, I manage to read the file and save all the info in a matrix, however, when I try to read from the matrix and link the different nodes between them I get the **segmentation fault** error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_N 10
#define MAX_P 20

//Declaracion del TDA cola
typedef struct Node {
   int rafaga;
   int id;
   struct Node *dret;
   struct Node *esq;
   int fiscals;
   int funcionaris;
   int advocats;
} tipoNodo;

typedef tipoNodo *pNodo; // tipo para declarar nodos a un entero

int nodes = 0, funcionarisTotals = 0, advocatsTotals = 0, fiscalsTotals = 0;
Node llista[MAX_N];
int graf[MAX_N*2][3];

void crearGraf(int graf[MAX_N*2][3]) {
    FILE *pf;
    char caracter; // variable de tipo caracter que va a servir para almacenar los caracteres leidos del archivo
    int valor, o, d;
    pf = fopen ("graf.txt","r"); // se abre el archivo en forma de lectura
    if (!pf) {  //en el caso que no se pueda abrir el archivo se manda un mensaje de error
        printf ("ERROR: el fichero  no existe o no se puede abrir\n");
        exit(-1); //mensaje "presiona una tecla para continuar"
    }
    else {
        int arestes = 0;
        nodes = int ((caracter=fgetc(pf))-'0'); 
        printf ("El graf te %d nodes\n", nodes);
        printf("abans del for de les rafagues\n");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nodes ; i++) {
            printf("abans de posar la id\n");
            llista[i].id = i;
            printf("abans de posar la rafaga\n");
            llista[i].rafaga = 1;
        }
        printf("despres del for de les rafagues\n");
        while (!feof (pf)) {
            int j = 0;
            caracter = fgetc(pf);
            o = int ((caracter = fgetc(pf))-'0'); //nodo origen
            caracter = fgetc(pf);
            d = int ((caracter = fgetc(pf))-'0');//nodo destino
            caracter = fgetc(pf);
            valor = int ((caracter =fgetc(pf))-'0');//pes de l'aresta
            if (o < 0 || d < 0 || valor < 0) break;
            printf ("%d %d %d\n",o,d,valor);
            graf[arestes][0] = o; // es guarda el pes de l'aresta que va de X -> Y a la matriu
            graf[arestes][1] = d;
            graf[arestes][2] = valor;
            printf("He llegit l'aresta %d\n", arestes);
            arestes++;
        }
        printf("Fora del while de llegir fitxer\n");
        fclose (pf);//se cierra el fichero
        printf("Abans del for de les arestes, fare %d voltes\n",arestes);
        for(int j = 0; j<arestes ; j++) {
        printf("Posant l'aresta del node %d al %d\n", graf[j][0],graf[j][1]);
            if(j == 0) {
                printf("posant la primera aresta de pes %d\n",graf[j][2]);
                *llista[graf[j][0]].dret = llista[graf[j][1]]; // enllacem l'aresta primera
                printf("primera aresta posada\n");
            } 
            if(j != 0 && (graf[j-1][0] == graf[j][0])) {
                printf("posant l'aresta del node %d and node %d com a fill esquerra\n",graf[j][0],graf[j][1]);
                *llista[graf[j][0]].esq = llista[graf[j][1]]; // enllacem l'aresta esquerra
            }
            else {
                printf("posant l'aresta del node %d and node %d com a fill dret\n",graf[j][0],graf[j][1]);
                *llista[graf[j][0]].dret = llista[graf[j][1]]; // enllacem l'aresta dreta
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    crearGraf(graf);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is when I try to link the first edge of the graph, in this line:

```
*llista[graf[j][0]].dret = llista[graf[j][1]]; // enllacem l'aresta primera
```

I think I'm messing up the type of the different variables. Also, all the printfs you see are to confirm that everything works just fine untill this point.

What am I missing again?

Thanks guys!

Comment: adjacency matrix can be done easily as a bitmap. If you want, I'll show you how to do it, it saves space x8

Answer (score 1):

You are de-referencing a null pointer when  you `*llista[graf[j][0]].dret` (because dret is  a pointer that is not set yet..)

i think what you meant to do is:

```
llista[graf[j][0]].dret = &llista[graf[j][1]];
```